# inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds equality constraints: int

Tags: java, generics

Trying to pass into a sort method:

```
simplequicksort(a1, size)
```

gives me the error:

> no suitable method found for simplequickSort(int[], int) method simplequickSort(T#1[], int) is not applicable
>   inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds equality constrants: int
>   upper bounds: Comparable)

I'm confused as to why it won't allow me to pass an array of ints into it when the parameter is an array of comparable.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might have to create an array of Integer[] rather than int[].  Comparable doesn't work for primitive types.

Comment: You can't use Java generics over primitive types, only over reference types

Comment: oh right thank you,